# JavaScript Factorial Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

In the following script, why does `badFactorial` blow the stack while `goodFactorial` works?

```
function badFactorial(n){
    if( n < 0){
        return 1;
    }
    if(n < 2){
        return n;
    }
    return badFactorial(n * (n-1));
}
function goodFactorial(n){
    if(n < 2){
        return n;
    }
    return goodFactorial(n-1) * n;
}
```

Comment: What do you call `badFactorial` with?

Comment: because it is intended to be so? (going by the name)

Comment: Because in badFactorial(n * (n-1)) the value of n is increasing exponentially always. It will never reach 0. That's why you are getting that error. While in second case, n is decremented each time which is very important for any recursive function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your creatng an endless loop with

`badFactorial(n * (n-1));`

it will just keep increasing.

say you passe in 7 .  instead of decreasing, youre doing

`return badfactorial(7 * 6)`

when you want :

`return badfactorial(6) * 7;`

so change the return to be like youre goodfactorial's ,

`badfactorial(n-1) * n;`

Answer (score 2):

Because in

```
badFactorial(n * (n-1))
```

the value of n is increasing always and it will never reach 0. That's why you are getting that error.

While in second case,

```
return goodFactorial(n-1) * n;
```

n is decremented each time which is very important for any recursive function.

Always remember in terms of recursive calls, the value of n or any argument must decrease else you will be getting stackoverflow error.