# Recursive JavaScript Function Results in "Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to create a simple recursive JavaScript function that produces factorials. I think I exhaust local memory in the callstack when running the code below and likely trigger an infinite recursion.

*Note: I want to use recursion to solve it.

```
function factorial(num, factor) {
  //loop through descending order multiply
  if (num === 1) {
    return newNum
  }
  let newNum = num --;
  let newProduct = num * newNum;
    //recurse
  return factorial(newNum, newProduct);
}

// Test cases
console.log(factorial(4)); // -> 24
console.log(factorial(6)); // -> 720
console.log(factorial(0)); // -> 1
```

Any suggestions as to how and why I should modify my above code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you write a non-recursive algorithm to calculate factorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231250/how-would-you-write-a-non-recursive-algorithm-to-calculate-factorials)

Comment: No, because I want to use recursion to solve it.

Comment: Your base case should be `num < 0` not `num === 1` if you want it to work on `0` input

Comment: `return product`. What product?

Comment: I don't get it. Where is the parameter 'factor' used in factorial? newNum is not defined either, that seems like bad practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Factorial Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318492/javascript-factorial-recursion)

Comment: No, because I'm not differentiating between "bad" or "good" factorial types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a problem with your decrement : That’s because the original value of the operand is being returned prior to the operand being changed(you need to change num-- by --num). Can you look this https://codeburst.io/javascript-increment-and-decrement-8c223858d5ed. You xan change your code by this

```
function factorial(num, factor=1) {
  //loop through descending order multiply
  if (num <= 1) {
    return factor
  }

  let newProduct = factor * num--;
    //recurse
  return factorial(num, newProduct);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the first two test cases. But for the last test case where input is 0 it still returns: "Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: Does newProduct take the place of factor=1 after the first iteration? I'm trying to make sense of the code to see exactly how the multiplied values are being saved in the parameter between each step in the loop.